# How to create a SHA-256 pin digest from a pfx file for Android network securit config?

Tags: android, openssl, certificate-pinning, android-network-security-config

I received a pfx file and the passphrase from the server administrator and I want to create an SHA-256 pin digest for the Android network security config.

How can I create the SHA-256 pin digest from a pfx file using openssl?

I referred openssl commands and the generated pins were invalid and rejected from server. But, I am able to call the api from postman with this pfx added in the certificate settings.